# spark-submit working for Python Programs but pyspark doesn't work

Tags: pyspark

Stating the obvious, I have recently installed SPARK on UBUNTU (VMWARE workstation). Below is my PC Specs.

Windows Dell laptop (running windows 10).

Installed VMWARE PRO 12 and loaded Ubuntu 15 on it.
Installed SPARK 1.6.1 / JAVA 1.7 / Python 2.7 and SCALA 2.11.8 using standard scripts.

I ran a sample program using spark submit command and it completes fine. But when i try to login to pyspark shell, I get the error message "pyspark: command not found"

What seems to be the problem. I can see all the files in the bin directory of spark (both pyspark and spark-submit).

Regards
VVSAUCSE

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is how it works, the full path with command name works fine. My apologies for not knowing earlier or trying it out.

/SparkPath/bin/pyspark works fine rather than just pyspark